# Want second last value only from date column from table- SQL

Tags: mysql

My table - Action_values is having following values

| ID | Action | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 99991231 |
| 1 | A5 | 20230702 |
| 1 | A8 | 20220510 |

Here, Value with 99991231 is the latest value,

I want second latest value only that is with 20230702 and Action - A5 should be available for further computation

Any help is highly appreciated

I tried below code

````
```
select A.*
from
(
       select ID,Action,max(Date) Date from Action_values
       group by ID,Action
)a
join
(       
       select ID, max(Date) Date from Action_values
       group by ID
)b
on a.ID=b.ID 
where a.Date<b.Date
and a.ID='1'
```
````

In result set, I am getting both values 20230702 and 20220510
I just want 20230702

Comment: date isn't a date datatype so what datatype is it?

Comment: P.Salmon - It is NVARCHAR

Comment: In that case convert to date or integer and adapt the answer in the link.